# Return Processed Data From The Fastest Thread Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I want to hit a URL which will eventually return the required data. Sometimes the requests timeout & it took upto 1 minute to receive the data. 
I want to make it as fast as possible. I am thinking of starting multiple threads & use the data from the earliest completed thread. Can anyone please help with the best approach?

I think I can do it via a infinite loop waiting for the result in an array from the thread but that seems to be a very inefficient way of doing it.

Comment: You want to make the same request over and over until one comes back?  You're going to likely make it worse by doing so.

Comment: This sounds like a great way to DOS a website... The longer it takes the server to respond, the more requests it receives!

Comment: Are you in control of this server? There are various techniques you could use to improve the implementation.

Comment: @TomLord No I am not in control of the target site's server. The website is very famous & they can easily handle the requests. The problem is they think I am a bot(which is true :P), and block requests. I am thinking to run X(i.e 4 or 8) number of threads in parallel with different proxies, and wait for the result. Once I receive successful result from the earliest thread, return the result. Could you please help me translate this idea into code?

Comment: Another approach to this problem is to start a worker when the end-user hit that URL and then display a list of workers for that user (or give him the ID of the worker that just started). Using that list (and their status), the end-user can then access the fetched data when the worker has done its job. `Resque` is great for that

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could be a strategy. It builds a list of threads which each attempt to set the `result` to some value. Then it sleeps until `result` is set and kills all the threads (setting a total 60 second timeout limit).

```
require 'timeout'

proxies = "proxy.com", "proxy.org" # replace with proxies

result = nil

Timeout.timeout(60) do
  threads = proxies.map do |proxy|
    Thread.new do
      result = get(proxy, target_url) # replace with HTTP call
    end
  end
  sleep 0.25 until result
  threads.each(&:kill)
end
```

You would probably want to modify this so that it checks that the response is successful, and not just that it's non-nil (for example, if it returns a 500 error).

Also, I would advise trying to adhere to the rate limits of the API, and check with their terms of service to ensure this is allowed.

Keep if mind that if you set a timeout of 60 seconds, that means anyone sending a request to this endpoinnt will have to wait up to 60 seconds for a response. This is usually undesirable, and people use async approaches instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing to get that data or what are the constraints of your client but it seems like you might need something like background jobs (see:  https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq or https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).
Depending on your exact case you can use various techniques to push the obtained data to the client.

Comment: I need to return the results in real time, not asynchronously.

Comment: doesn't matter. See the comment from @MrYoshiji